# Tried creating and writing to a file, but I'm getting error messages

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter, file-writing

I'm trying to learn how to create a file and write to it on Java. I've been watching videos online on how to do it. Unfortunately using the exact same code as the person doing the lesson, I come up with these errors which I don't understand.

---

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at CompanyAdder.main(CompanyAdder.java:26)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/Users/mychalco/Desktop/ASreader.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at CompanyAdder.main(CompanyAdder.java:35)
```

---

I know that there's apparently an error on line 26 and 35, but I don't understand what else is happening. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompanyAdder 
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String addCompanyName = "Y";
        //String companyName;

        File newFile = new File("C:/Users/mychalco/Desktop/ASreader.txt");

        if(newFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("The file already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try
            {
                FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(newFile);
                BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);
                /*System.out.println("Add a company name: ");

                while (addCompanyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    companyName = sc.next();
                    buffW.write(companyName);
                    System.out.println("Do you want to add another company? (Y/N) ");
                    addCompanyName = sc.next();
                }*/
                buffW.close();
                System.out.println("Company names added!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Ignore the comment lines, those were some alterations I tried to make to the code.

Thanks, Cheers.

Comment: can you please try this `File newFile = new File("C:\\Users\\mychalco\\Desktop\\ASreader.txt");`

Comment: If your code is the exact same as the person, then do you have a file at `C:/Users/mychalco/Desktop/ASreader.txt`

Comment: Are you on a windows or unix/linux system? Your file path is windows, but based on line 2 of the error message Java thinks it is running on Unix.

Comment: @YCF_L: Windows handles forward slashes fine.

Comment: thank you @JonSkeet

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help. I tried running the code on my Windows computer and it worked. Then I looked back to my mac and altered the "newFile" by removing C:. That seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `File.separator` in this way:

```
File newFile = new File("C:"+File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"mychalco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator+"ASreader.txt");
```

Comment: Well it would be better to use `Paths.of`... but I don't think that's the problem here.